# SQL ERROR ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT Person_ID, CONCAT('First_name','Surname') AS "Person_Name", Next_of_kin, '~ No next of kin ~' AS Next_of_kin_name, Next_of_kin_age AS NULL  
FROM PERSON  
WHERE Next_of_kin IS NULL
UNION
SELECT Childs.Person_ID, CONCAT('Childs.First_name','Childs.Surname') AS "Person_name", Next_of_kin, CONCAT('Fathers.First_name','Fathers.Surname') AS "Next_of_kin_name",TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(Fathers.birth_date, 'YYYY')
(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY')- TO_CHAR(Birth_date, 'YYYY')) AS Next_of_kin_age 
FROM Person Childs, Person Fathers
WHERE Childs.next_of_kin = Fathers.Person_ID
AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(Fathers.birth_date, 'YYYY') >= 50;
```

Comment: `NULL` is a reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words), and cannot be used as column alias. Chose another alias, or delimit as `"NULL"`.

Comment: There's also a missing comma, or someting else, in the second SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

- Last **column Name** returned as `NULL` but actually u want return value as `NULL` for `Next_of_kin_age`.
- Also, You have missed operator in last column of second select, I have assumed minus operator.

  TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(Fathers.birth_date, 'YYYY')
  (TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY')- TO_CHAR(Birth_date, 'YYYY')) AS Next_of_kin_age

Try This

```
SELECT Person_ID, 
       CONCAT('First_name','Surname') AS "Person_Name", 
       Next_of_kin, 
       '~ No next of kin ~' AS Next_of_kin_name, 
       NULL AS Next_of_kin_age 
FROM PERSON  
WHERE Next_of_kin IS NULL
UNION
SELECT Childs.Person_ID, 
       CONCAT('Childs.First_name','Childs.Surname') AS "Person_name", 
       Next_of_kin, 
       CONCAT('Fathers.First_name','Fathers.Surname') AS "Next_of_kin_name",
       TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(Fathers.birth_date, 'YYYY') - (TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(Birth_date, 'YYYY')) AS Next_of_kin_age 
FROM Person Childs, Person Fathers
WHERE Childs.next_of_kin = Fathers.Person_ID
AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(Fathers.birth_date, 'YYYY') >= 50;
```